# Writing a list of python console output to text file

Tags: python-3.x, pathlib

I am a newb to python and working on writing a file from the list of devices printed to the python console. I am using pathlib and trying to write the entire list to a text file. I have tried many configurations but for some reason it only writes the first device or a blank text file.

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

```
results = nb.dcim.devices.filter(q='xxxx')

# Print results to console

for device in results:
    print(device.name)

# Write data to file

path = pathlib.Path("C:\\Temp\\device_inventory.txt")
path.write_text()
```

Comment: It appears you are not actually writing any device information, merely printing it. Please [edit] the code to show the actual attempt at writing the data to the file.

Comment: This writes a text file to C:\Temp it does not write the entire list to the text file just the first line of output. I hope that makes sense?
path = pathlib.Path("C:\\Temp\\router_inventory.txt")
path.write_text()

Comment: This will help: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp

Comment: The code shown *prints the device* name and *writes nothing* to the file (thereby creating an empty file). The question states that the goal is to *write some device data* to the file. Please show the code trying to do that.

Comment: @jdaz All of the linked examples are anti-patterns (using explicit ``.close`` instead of ``with``) and do not use ``pathlib`` as desired.